# Flask giving error 400 on file upload

Tags: python, upload, flask

I have the following

```
<form action="classify_upload" method="post" id="upload-form">
    <input type="file" name="imagefile" id="imagefile"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And in my flask webapp I have the following rule:

```
@webapp.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    try:
        imagefile = flask.request.files['imagefile']
        ...
    except Exception as err:
        ...
```

But I am getting a `error 400: bad request`, which from my googling tells me Flask can not find the file under the key `'imagefile'` which is the name of the input in the html. Any ideas why it is not finding it?

Answer (score 9):

Turns out I need to include the `enctype` in the form, so the html should be

```
<form action="classify_upload" method="post" id="upload-form"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="imagefile" id="imagefile"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```